# Stored procedure to get values in the Html table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am trying to get the values into the html table.  There are two database tables from where i need to fetch the values and display in the html table.
I have written a stored procedure but it doesn't work.
Scenario:
User need to enter the Quarter and year . Based on the input provided I will get a summary table. The summary table should have columns:  ID, Project, S1,P1. 
ID and Project are retrieved from db table `ProjectDetails` and S1, P1 are coming from `Details`

For example: 
Tables look like this:

Project Details:

```
    ID   | Project 
------------------------
    PR_1 | the project
    PR_2 | the second project
```

Details table:

PR_1 the project

```
Item | Status | Amount

ABC  | S1     | 1000.00
XYZ  | S1     | 200.00
Test1| S1     | 300.00
Test2| P1     | 4000.00
```

So the summary table should be :

```
ID | Project            | S1  | P1
PR1| the project        | 1500| 4000
PR2| the second project | 0   | 0
```

Here is the stored proc:

```
create proc [dbo].[Summary]
@Quarter int,
@Year int
AS
BEGIN

Declare @S1 AS decimal(18,0)
Declare @P1 AS decimal(18,0)


 SELECT BD.ID, BD.Project,Status,((Select SUM(Amount)from Details where Status='S1') as 'S1'), ((Select SUM(Amount) from Details where Status='P1') as 'P1')

 FROM ProjectDetails (NOLOCK) BD
 inner join Details (NOLOCK) D on BD.Project = D.Project

 WHERE BD.Quarter = @Quarter and BD.Year = @Year and BD.Project = D.Project
 Group By BD.LineID, BD.Project,Status
END
```

Comment: Be careful with those NOLOCK hints. They carry a lot more baggage than most people realize. Things like missing and/or duplicate rows. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/ Also if you are going to use query hints omitting the WITH keyword has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create proc [dbo].[Summary]
@Quarter int,
@Year int
AS
BEGIN

Declare @SC AS decimal(18,0)
Declare @PO AS decimal(18,0)
Declare @INV AS decimal(18,0)

 SELECT BD.ID, BD.Project,Status,(Select SUM(Amount) as S1 from Details a where Status='S1' and BD.Project = a.Project), (Select SUM(Amount) as P1 from Details b where Status='P1' and BD.Project = b.Project)

 FROM ProjectDetails (NOLOCK) BD
 inner join Details (NOLOCK) D on BD.Project = D.Project

 WHERE BD.Quarter = @Quarter and BD.Year = @Year and BD.Project = D.Project
 Group By BD.LineID, BD.Project,Status
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create proc [dbo].[Summary]
@Quarter int,
@Year int
AS
BEGIN

Declare @SC AS decimal(18,0)
Declare @PO AS decimal(18,0)
Declare @INV AS decimal(18,0)

 SELECT BD.ID, BD.Project,Status,(Select SUM(Amount)from Details a where Status='S1' and BD.Project = a.Project) as S1, (Select SUM(Amount) from Details b where Status='P1' and BD.Project = b.Project) as P1

 FROM ProjectDetails (NOLOCK) BD
 inner join Details (NOLOCK) D on BD.Project = D.Project

 WHERE BD.Quarter = @Quarter and BD.Year = @Year and BD.Project = D.Project
 Group By BD.LineID, BD.Project,Status
END
```

Hope this helps, I have added the missing condition in your inner query

Comment: does this gives you the desired output

Comment: I dont think its correct as BD.Project = Details.Project can't be added in inner query because from clause includes Table 'Details'

Comment: hey i changed the placement of as. looks like its working. Atleast notgiving an errror. I have posted that as an answer. Thanks :)